# Power Automate "Azure Cosmos DB" connector "Get a document (V2)" is not working

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, power-automate

I am using Power Automate to do some operations in Azure Cosmos DB. Further I need to fetch the record from a table using the primary key. To get this record, I have used "Get a document (V2)" but somehow this is not working. It is giving me an error even if I have a record exists with the same GUID that I am providing as ID in this connector.
Below is the error that I am receiving.

{
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "Entity with the specified id does not exist in the system. More info: https://aka.ms/cosmosdb-tsg-not-found, {....}
}

Comment: Got any further info? Like screenshots, details of the Cosmos item? Anything else for us to help.

Comment: Please edit to provide more detail. For example: did you provide a value for the partition key? (common mistake: providing the *name* of the property serving as partition key, instead of the *value* of the partition key property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much [@David Mokogon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272109/david-makogon) and [@Matias Quaranta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641598/matias-quaranta)

Its working after I have provided Partition key value with " (Double Quote).
Previously I had tried with ' (Single Quote) and alone.